# Solve the differential equation: $\frac{dy} {dx} - \frac{y} {\sin x} =\tan\frac{1}{2}x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

This is my ex. $$\frac{dy} {dx} - \frac{y} {\sin x} =\tan\frac{1}{2}x.$$
So..
I calcule From the formula
$y=c * e^{-\int \frac{1}{sinx}dx} = c*e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln|\frac{1-cosx}{1+cosx}|}=c*\sqrt{|\frac{1-cosx}{1+cosx}|}$

How to calculate $y'$? Including absolute value and ranges...
 [image]!

Comment: The DE in title and body are different.....

Comment: Note that the absolute value bars are unnecessary because $1+\cos x$ and $1-\cos x$ are never negative.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'- \frac{y} {\sin x} =\tan\frac{1}{2}x$$
The easiest way. Integrating factor is:
$$\mu(x)=exp(-\int \frac {dx}{\sin x})=exp(-\ln(\tan (x/2))$$
$$\mu(x)=\tan^{-1}(x/2)=\cot(x/2)$$
The equation becomes simply:
$$\cot(x/2)y'-\frac 1 2 \dfrac y {(\sin^2(x/2))}=1$$
$$\cot(x/2)y'+(\cot(x/2))'y=1$$
$$(\cot\left(\frac x 2 \right)y)'=1$$
Integrate.
$$\cot\left(\frac x 2 \right)y=x+C$$
$$ \implies y(x)=\dfrac {x+C}{\cot\left(\frac x 2 \right)}=\tan\left(\frac x 2 \right)(x+C)$$

Comment: Why @DougM ? Do you think its wrong ? I integrated the inverse sine function with Weierstrass substitution

Comment: Sorry, it is fine.

Comment: No problem @DougM